# Axios request to protected pages does not redirect to login page using Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios

I am building an webapp using Spring Boot and Spring Security. In my extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class I have protected an endpoint that can only be accessed by authenticated users. which is managed by a @RestController class that returns a string.

> .antMatchers("/test").authenticated()

This endpoint is managed by a @RestController class which has a method that returns a string.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRest {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("test");
    }
}
```

If I am not authenticated and enter this endpoint in the browser, it redirects to login page.

The problem is that I am using vue.js and axios on client side. If I am authenticated and use axios to make a get to this end point,

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/test")
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
     })
     .catch((error => console.log(error)))
```

I receive a normal response with status 200 and correct response data ("test"). But if I'm not authenticated it doesn't redirect to login page. It returns a response status 200 and the whole html content of the login page in the response data instead.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to redirect the request to login page when using axios in this situation?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I've changed the whole project. Now I'm using a restful API and all redirections are controlled on client side.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't redirect because you made an XHR request so it's up to you to handle it.

On your backend, Spring Boot, you can try checking if the request is an XHR request and if so respond with a JSON or a redirect.

Depending on what you decided with, you can redirect manually either using the location from the JSON or the `Location` response header.